# How to Parameterize in Soap UI Load Test

Tags: soapui

I have a Webservice Request which is Exposed..

I need to use parameterization for each Request. I have used Groovy Script to Change couple of values in serial.

This is the result when not parameterization using groovy script in load test.[image]

But When I introduce Groovy script to randomize some values. I am not getting proper result.. All are displayed as Zero even if it shows 100% completed
Once it is completed. it is not showing result. [image]

When I Stop Running it is displaying result but it is drastic change in the result. How to parameterize in load test.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

When I check the highlighted items. It is working fine..